# Excel keeps changing data on a seperate worksheet form

Tags: replace, excel-formula

I am in the process of creating some forms that I use every day at work, in excel. On the first form I am doing a VBA lookup from an external database and depending on the selected item the user chooses from the drop down list, it populates the required information on the cell containing the VBA look up formula. This is all working great but one thing that we are required to do when ordering with the form is, we have to track those purchases on another form. I created the second form as well and it populates all the information from the order form to their corresponding cells on the tracking form. The issue I am having is when information is changed in the referenced cells of the order form the information is changed on the tracking form replacing the 1st orders information with the next orders information. What I have been researching (to no avail) is, how to keep the previous orders information on the tracking sheet even though the order form is cleared to imput another order. When imputting the second orders information instead of erasing the previous orders information on the tracking sheet I want the information being imputed on the order form for the second order to  start on the next available colum in their corresponding cell references.

That is one problem the other one is this. The order tracking forms have a set amount of columns of that information can be put in before it get to the bottom of the form. How do I get it to start another tracking form and continue tracking orders on its first available column and once again when getting to the bottom start another form?

I know this was a lot of information and I hope I explained it well enough for you to understand. I was recently brought around to the use of macros but I am still a NOOB when it comes to these. If using macros is the most effficient way to do what I need and have to use one or two or three to get this task met, can you please provide me with the coding for each needed? Thank you again ahead of time.

```
     V/R
```

Logistician and loving it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you copy the *value* from the dynamic sheet to the tracking sheet. If you copy the *formula,* it will also be dynamic.

For example, let's say you have the following spreadsheet:

```
        A        B        C        D
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
  1 |     42 |  =$a$1 |        |        |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

and the following code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("a1").Value = 42                 ' ensure source data as expected'

    Range("c1").Value = Range("b1").Value  ' copy value '

    Range("b1").Copy                       ' copy formula '
    Range("d1").PasteSpecial

    Range("a1").Value = 0                  ' change source data '
End Sub
```

When you run that code, `c1` get the current value of `a1` which is 42.  However, `d1` gets the current formula from `b1` which is a non-relative reference to `a1`, so you end up with:

```
        A        B        C        D
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
  1 |     0  |  =$a$1 |     42 |  =$a$1 |
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

or `c1` being the only cell holding the historical record (because both `b1` and `d1` are formulaic references, they will reflect changes made to the original data source).